# Create A client that can receive and send messages at the same time.In Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, server, client

I am trying to do A chat between clients(android) to a server with a socket connection. I want my client to be able to send messages to the server and at the same time to listen to messages that the server is sending back. I was able to do a thread that will do the connection and opens a thread that sends a message whenever the client presses a button but I don't know how to add a thread that will listen to server response.

here is my client code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    TextView tv1;
    Button btnSend;
    EditText etMessage;

    String message_data;

    PrintWriter output;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        etMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_message);
        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);

        doConnection("Idan", "uid2");



    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v== btnSend)
        {
            message_data = etMessage.getText().toString();
            new Thread(new ThreadSend(message_data)).start();

        }

    }

    public class ThreadSend implements Runnable{

        private String messageTOSend;

        ThreadSend(String message){
            this.messageTOSend = message;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            output.write(messageTOSend);
            output.flush();
        }
    }




    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            try {
                Socket s = new Socket("10.0.0.5", 7979);
                output = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
                String connection_data = "Idan//uid1";
                output.write(connection_data);
                output.flush();

                output.write("Hello");
                output.flush();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    private void doConnection(String userUid, String destinationUid) {
        thread.start();
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

can someone help me or give me any advice where I can find information about it

Comment: What is the problem in starting a thread that reads?

Comment: But why would you open a new thread to listen to the servers response? Just read the response in the same thread as used for sending. Read the response directly after you sent the message.

Comment: The main idea is that the chat will be between two different clients so I don't know when I will get a response.  at the time that I am waiting I want to be able to continue to send messages

Comment: Well then just open a listening thread.

Comment: how should I do it? I looked for something that does that but I still didn't find it?

Comment: @idan, This seems like Producer and Consumer problem, google it, also Rabbit MQ is good example for this type of use case

Comment: If you can open a thread for sending/writing then what is the problem opening a thread for receiving/reading?